# preg_match returns 1 although it shouldnt

Tags: php, regex

```
echo preg_match("/090\d{5}/","090327112");
echo preg_match("/090\d{5}/","0903271122");
```

each of these echos 1 and i dont understand why, it matches 090 but it has more then 5 digits following...

used it also https://regex101.com/ and it says :

[image]

Comment: Try using anchors `^090\d{5}$`

Comment: I just echoed preg_match("/090\d{5}/","abcdefghijk") and got 0. The 1 you received must just be saying that - a match was found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the start of string `^` and end of string `$` anchors in your pattern:

```
echo preg_match("/^090\d{5}$/","090327112");
```

This will make it so that it will only match strings which start with `090` and then have any 5 digits before the end of string.

[**regex101 demo**](https://regex101.com/r/o6IMbS/1)

Comment: Note that your pattern matches also the string `"09012345\n"`. To prevent `$` to match before the trailing newline, you can ever add the D modifier or to use `\z` in place of `$`.